# Why Aqua and Ruby have only one eye with star?

Tags: oshi-no-ko

In the anime *Oshi no Ko*. Ai has eyes with star but her children Aqua and Ruby have only one eye with star. I haven't read the manga. Does it have any specific reason? Is it related to their genes? What does eye with star mean?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The star in the eyes is not an actual physical thing characters in story can see. It displays Ai's star power, and how her two children each inherited some of her star power.

It's a narrative device to display the character's internal emotions without having to state them out loud.